# Why do I have to use core.CreateIntVarFromTo to get this Sudoku solver to work?

Tags: go, constraint-programming

I'm using the Golang gofd package, to provide a constraints satisfaction solution to solve the Sudoku problem.  I create the following

```
package main

import (
    "bitbucket.org/gofd/gofd/core"
    "bitbucket.org/gofd/gofd/propagator"
    "bitbucket.org/gofd/gofd/labeling"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "fmt"
)

var ROWS = []string{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"}
var COLS = []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}


var SQUARE1 = []string{
    "A!", "A2", "A3",
    "B1", "B2", "B3",
    "C1", "C2", "C3"}

var SQUARE2 = []string{
    "A4", "A5", "A6",
    "B4", "B5", "B6",
    "C4", "C5", "C6"}

var SQUARE3 = []string{
    "A7", "A8", "A9",
    "B7", "B8", "B9",
    "C7", "C8", "C9"}

var SQUARE4 = []string{
    "D!", "D2", "D3",
    "E1", "E2", "E3",
    "F1", "F2", "F3"}

var SQUARE5 = []string{
    "D4", "D5", "D6",
    "E4", "E5", "E6",
    "F4", "F5", "F6"}

var SQUARE6 = []string{
    "D7", "D8", "D9",
    "E7", "E8", "E9",
    "F7", "F8", "F9"}

var SQUARE7 = []string{
    "G!", "G2", "G3",
    "H1", "H2", "H3",
    "I1", "I2", "I3"}

var SQUARE8 = []string{
    "G4", "G5", "G6",
    "H4", "H5", "H6",
    "I4", "I5", "I6"}

var SQUARE9 = []string{
    "G7", "G8", "G9",
    "H7", "H8", "H9",
    "I7", "I8", "I9"}

var SQUARES = [][]string{
    SQUARE1, SQUARE2, SQUARE3,
    SQUARE4, SQUARE5, SQUARE6,
    SQUARE7, SQUARE8, SQUARE9}

type Grid struct {
    Grid map[string]int
}

func create() Grid {
    grid := map[string]int{}
    return Grid{grid}
}

func (g *Grid) load(filename string) {
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    err := json.Unmarshal(body, g)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}


func main() {
    store := core.CreateStore()
    n := 9

    sudoku := map[string]core.VarId{}

    for _, row := range ROWS {
        for _, col := range COLS {
            varname := fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", row, col)
            sudoku[varname] = core.CreateIntVarFromTo(varname, store, 1, n)
        }
    }

    for _, square := range SQUARES {
        area := make([]core.VarId, len(square))
        for i, key := range square {
            area[i] = sudoku[key]
        }

        prop := propagator.CreateAlldifferent(area...)
        store.AddPropagators(prop)
    }

    for _, row := range ROWS {
        area := make([]core.VarId, len(COLS))
        for i, col := range COLS {
            varname := fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", row, col)
            area[i] = sudoku[varname]
        }
        prop := propagator.CreateAlldifferent(area...)
        store.AddPropagators(prop)
    }

    for _, col := range COLS {
        area := make([]core.VarId, len(COLS))
        for i, row := range ROWS {
            varname := fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", row, col)
            area[i] = sudoku[varname]
        }
        prop := propagator.CreateAlldifferent(area...)
        store.AddPropagators(prop)
    }

    grid := create()
    grid.load("test2.json")

    for k,v := range grid.Grid {
        prop := propagator.CreateXeqC(sudoku[k], v)
        store.AddPropagators(prop)
    }

    consistent := store.IsConsistent()
    fmt.Printf("consistent: %v \n", consistent)

    query := labeling.CreateSearchAllQuery()
    solutionFound := labeling.Labeling(store, query,labeling.SmallestDomainFirst, labeling.InDomainMin)
    fmt.Printf("solutionFound: %v \n", solutionFound)
    if solutionFound {
        resultSet := query.GetResultSet()
        for _, result := range resultSet {
            values := map[string]int{}

            for k,v := range result {
                id := store.GetName(k)
                values[string(id)] = v
            }

            for _, row := range ROWS {
                for _, col := range COLS {
                    key := fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", row, col)
                    fmt.Print(values[key], " ")
                }
                fmt.Println()
            }


        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice I'm loading from a JSON file 'test2.json'.  This files contents are as follows

```
{"Grid": {
  "A1": 6, "A2": 3, "A3": 2, "A6": 7, "A7": 1,
  "B3": 7, "B4": 6, "B5": 2, "B7": 8, "B8": 9,
  "C2": 5,
  "D1": 5, "D3": 3, "D6": 9,
  "E2": 2, "E3": 6, "E5": 1, "E7": 9, "E8": 4,
  "F4": 5, "F7": 7, "F9": 2,
  "G8": 8,
  "H2": 6, "H3": 4, "H5": 8, "H6": 3, "H7": 5,
  "I3": 8, "I4": 1, "I7": 3, "I8": 6, "I9": 7}}
```

This program doesn't work, coming up wi the following.

```
consistent: false 
solutionFound: false
```

Unless I add the following var

```
core.CreateIntVarFromTo("total", store, 50, 50)
```

In which case I do get an answer.  Why do I need to do this?  As far as I can see the other constraints should be enough.  You're after all wanting the row to have all different values within the domain of 1 to 9, same with columns, and units (which I label as squares here).  There should be only one answer to any sudoku problem, and I shouldn't need to add

```
core.CreateIntVarFromTo("total", store, 50, 50)
```

It doesn't matter what value you give it, as you'll get as many answers as the allowed by this var.  So if I set it like this

```
core.CreateIntVarFromTo("total", store, 10, 11)
```

I'll get 2 results, of the same numbers.  Also another thing that puzzles me is if I set the to value to below 10

```
core.CreateIntVarFromTo("total", store, 9, 9)
```

it fails to be consistent and no solution is found, but if I set the to value to 10 or above it comes up with an answer as many times starting from from, up to to, in the following case it will give 3 results

```
core.CreateIntVarFromTo("total", store, 9, 12)
```

What fact am I missing here?

Comment: I can appreciate there is a typo in my code here, but I can't accept this makes it a bad question.  Could you please tell me, whoever is downvoting me, as to why you're doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I have to confess that I'm not a Go programmer, but I might look more into Go and the gofd package (which I didn't know about; thanks for the tip).

I don't know why "total" make the model behaves as it does, but why are you naming some of the cells with an "!" instead of "1", e.g. "A!", "D!", and "G!"?

When I replace "!" with "1", the correct and unique solution (without the "total" variable) is shown:

```
consistent: true 
solutionFound: true 
6 3 2 8 9 7 1 5 4 
4 1 7 6 2 5 8 9 3 
8 5 9 4 3 1 2 7 6 
5 4 3 2 7 9 6 1 8 
7 2 6 3 1 8 9 4 5 
9 8 1 5 4 6 7 3 2 
3 7 5 9 6 2 4 8 1 
1 6 4 7 8 3 5 2 9 
2 9 8 1 5 4 3 6 7
```

I added the following to check for the unicity of the solution:

```
query2 := labeling.CreateSearchAllQuery()
solutionFound2 := labeling.Labeling(store, query2, labeling.SmallestDomainFirst, labeling.InDomainMin)
if solutionFound2 {
    println("The Sudoku problem has", len(query2.GetResultSet()), "solutions.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I see my obvious mistake. Well not so obvious. As to total, it means nothing, I just stumbled across using it to get an answer when I was trying to figure out why it wasn't working. I'll correct the mistake and see what happens. I hate typos :-(

Comment: Yep, it was the ! instead of 1 that caused me problems.  Thanks.